# React Native Firebase + Redux (additional userProfile information)

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to build out a sign up flow that involves Firebase authentication (this works fine, easy implementation), but also additional profile information (firstName, lastName, avatar, etc).

I found that using react-redux is probably the way to go here, but I cannot find any tutorials online that focus on React Native, Firebase, and Redux. Anything I do find, doesn't seem to work.

Should I abandon react-native-firebase for react-redux-firebase? I'm in the early stages, so would prefer to make the best decisions now. I will also be handling some other Realtime Database data as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a collection "users" in your firestore database, and every time a user registered, besides going into { authentication } dash he will also be created at the collection.

because you didn't attach code, I don't sure how similar it is going to look (this code use react-redux-firebase ex https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase) but -

-------------------------------redux-action

```
export const register = newUser => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirebase, getFirestore }) => {
     const firebase = getFirebase();
     const firestore = getFirestore();
     firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email, newUser.password)

        //after auth we want to create user object in firestore collection with same uid

        .then(resp => {
            return firestore
                .collection('users')
                .doc(resp.user.uid)
                .set({
                    name: newUser.name,
                    email: newUser.email
                });
        })
        .then(() => {
            dispatch({ type: 'REGISTER' });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'ERROR',
                err
            });
        });
     };
 };
```

and then by having objects to all the users, it is dynamic and easy to config by snapshot

---